# See private browsing history in High Sierra

Tags: safari, high-sierra

I was on private browsing mode (on a MacBook Pro / High Sierra) and searched and found websites that I need for my work. Unfortunately I did not realize it and now I don't even know how to retrieve my history of private browsing to see the exact websites I visited. Is there any possible way?

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of private browsing is to not store a persistent record of website data. It's not possible to find a history for a private browsing tab once you've closed the tab.